# Download image from the database using hyperlink in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink

I have a website, and in admin login I wanted to see all the order details.
This is how my web site looks:[image]

I am getting the data from the database and viewed it using "Datagrid"
So this is some portion of coding about data retrieving.

```
<ItemStyle Width="100%" VerticalAlign="Top"></ItemStyle>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:DataGrid id=Datagrid2 runat="server" DataSource='<%# getTicketsDataSource( (string)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CartID").ToString() ) %>' BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="1" GridLines="Horizontal" Font-Name="Verdana" Font-Size="x-small" Width="100%" AutogenerateColumns="False">
<HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" />
<ItemStyle BackColor="White" />
<AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="Silver" />

<Columns>
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Heiskort">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Title") + " " + DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ProductVariant") %>' ID="Label1">
</asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>

<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Navn">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.FirstName") + " " + DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.LastName") %>' ID="Label2">
</asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>

<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Bilde">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/admin/skishop/photo.gif" NavigateUrl="">     
</asp:HyperLink>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

So this is not the complete code, but some parts of data retrieving. Actually, it is about first three columns of the table.

So this is my question.

In the picture, I attached above that there is a column called "Bilde". That is the profile picture. What I want is, when the admin clicks on this icon, I want to download the profile picture which is saved in the database.

I have no idea about what to put on "NavigateUrl" attribute. But I want when I click on the icon, relevant image saved in the DB should be downloaded. So please someone help me tackle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of Hyperlink you can use ImageButton

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="imgbtn" ImageUrl="~/admin/skishop/photo.gif" 
                        onclick="imgbtn_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
```

Cs Code:

```
protected void imgbtn_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
           ImageButton btn = sender as ImageButton;
            int profileid = Convert.ToInt32(btn.CommandArgument);
            loadImage(profileid);
        }

    public void loadImage(int profileid)
    {  
    DataTable dt = GetData(profileid);// return data from database in this function
                if (dt != null)
                {
                    Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])dt.Rows[0]["Imagedata"];
                    Response.Buffer = true;
                    Response.Charset = "";
                    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                    Response.ContentType = dt.Rows[0]["ContentType"].ToString();
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename="
                    + dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString());
                    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
                    Response.Flush();
                    Response.End();
                }
        }
```

Comment: actually the code i pasted here is not developed by me.I am just doing some modifications to this code.In this code the developer used "<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Title") + " " + DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ProductVariant") %>" to get the text from the DB.Here there is no ID is passed.So in my case what do you mean by "ID"?

Comment: Punuth,Identify unique column and bind it from your database table to imageButton ,so you can fetch relevant image on click ImageButton.I think in your case **Title** column  can not be treat as **ID**.Please look for other column also.